# java while statement error

Tags: java, while-loop

hi this is my code :

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
       int a,b;
       String rep="YES";

       while (rep.equals("YES")){
          System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
          a=sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Please enter you second number: ");
          b=sc.nextInt();
          int  c=a+b;
          System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: "+c);
          rep=" ";
          while (!rep.equals("YES") && !rep.equals("NO")){
             System.out.println("Would you retry ( YES/NO): ");        
             sc.nextLine();
             rep=sc.nextLine();
          }       
       }
       System.out.println("Thanks to use mY proggram!");          
}}
```

**My probleme in this code :
When i run this app , Firstly :**

Please enter your first number:

45

Please enter you second number:

45

The sum of a and b is: 90

Would you retry ( YES/NO):

**I write something else like "dgdg"
That would be**

Please enter your first number:

45

Please enter you second number:

45

The sum of a and b is: 90

Would you retry ( YES/NO):

dgdg

Would you retry ( YES/NO):

**this time when i write "YES"
it appears another line to write something like this :**

Please enter your first number:

45

Please enter you second number:

45

The sum of a and b is: 90

Would you retry ( YES/NO):

dgdg

Would you retry ( YES/NO):

YES

YES

Please enter your first number:

**hope to find a solution**

Comment: Instead of using the while loop, try do-while and check for the condition at the end of the loop,that way you can get the input from the user first and then use it accordingly, the concurrent use of `goto` statements can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

try this (proceeds with calculation if the answer is YES, or else for NO or garbage input it stops the program) - also does away with the branching in while within the while loop

```
public class Calc {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a, b;
        String rep = "YES";

        while (rep.equals("YES")) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Please enter you second number: ");
            b = sc.nextInt();
            int c = a + b;
            System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: " + c);
            do {
                System.out.println("Would you retry ( YES/NO): ");
                rep = sc.next();
            } while(!("YES".equals(rep) || "NO".equals(rep)));
            if("NO".equals(rep)) {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Thanks to use mY proggram!");
    }
}
```

I have updated the answer so that it continues for user input "YES", stops for user input "NO" and keeps prompting for any other user entry.

Comment: i want to force the user to write only yes or no !

Comment: @user2439917 done, should work for YES, NO. making it case insensitive if needed is left as an exercise for you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
            sc.nextLine();
            rep = sc.nextLine();
```

write

```
           rep = sc.nextLine();
```

Because when you give sc.nextLine() twice, it will expect two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Few things:

1. `sc.nextInt()` wont consume new line mark, so if you will use `rep = sc.nextLine();` it will return empty String. To get rid of that problem you can use `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine)` instead, or add `sc.nextLine()` after each `sc.nextInt()`, or just use `sc.next()` when you used `sc.nextLine()`
2. probably because of point 1 you had to use

   ```
   sc.nextLine();
   rep = sc.nextLine();
   ```

   now you can skip first `sc.nextLine();` and just use `rep = sc.nextLine();`
3. Use `rep.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")` to also accept `Yes`, `yes`, `yEs` and so on.

So your code can look like this

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int a, b;
String rep = "YES";

while (rep.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")) {
    System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
    a = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter you second number: ");
    b = sc.nextInt();

    int c = a + b;
    System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: " + c);
    rep = " ";

    while (!rep.equalsIgnoreCase("YES") && !rep.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
        System.out.println("Would you retry (YES/NO): ");
        rep = sc.next();
    }
}
System.out.println("Thanks to use mY proggram!");
```

Comment: Thanks Pshemo,vani,Scorpion for your help , i appreciate

Comment: @user2439917 What problems do you still have to solve in your code? Code from my answer seems to do exactly what you ware trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the code to use following code.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
       Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
       int a,b;
       String rep="YES";

       while (rep.equals("YES")){
          System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
          a=sc.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Please enter you second number: ");
          b=sc.nextInt();
          int  c=a+b;
          System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: "+c);
          rep="";
          while (!rep.equals("YES") && !rep.equals("NO")){
             System.out.println("Would you retry ( YES/NO): ");        
             rep=sc.next();
             System.out.println("Rep is : "+rep);
          }       
       }
       System.out.println("Thanks to use mY proggram!");          
}
```

Comment: i want to force the user to write  just yes or no !

Comment: I think it is happening because any other input from user takes him back to same question. Else may be you would like have something on UI having just two radio buttons so as to avoid any other input.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you all ! the

```
 i.nextLine();
```

should not place below this method :

```
System.out.println("Would you retry ( YES/NO): ");
```

it should be after the second `whil` statment

This is the correct code :

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Calc {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   int a,b;
   String rep="YES";

   while (rep.equals("YES")){
      System.out.println("Please enter your first number: ");
      a=sc.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please enter you second number: ");
      b=sc.nextInt();
      int  c=a+b;
      System.out.println("The sum of a and b is: "+c);
      rep=" ";
      sc.nextLine();
      while (!rep.equals("YES") && !rep.equals("NO")){
         System.out.println("Would you retry ( YES/NO): ");        

         rep=sc.nextLine();
      }       
   }


    System.out.println("Thanks to use mY proggram!");          
}}
```